# A complex number raised to a power.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> $(4\sqrt{3} +4i)^3 = $ ?

I had $148.1028 + 4.0611i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4^3(\sqrt3^3+i3\sqrt3^2-3\sqrt3-i)=64(i8).$$

Answer (score 3):

Factoring gives

$$(4\sqrt{3}+4i)^3=8^3\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}i\right)^3\\$$
$$=8^3\left(e^{i\frac\pi6}\right)^3\\$$
$$=8^3e^{i\frac\pi2}\\$$
$$=512i$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

It's $\left[8\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3+i}2\right)\right]^3$

Comment: I’m so sorry but I’m kind of new to complex number but I tried using the de moivre theorm and what I simplified to was kind of different..I wish you would be a little more clear to me ..Thank you

Comment: what did you get for the magnitude and argument?

Comment: I had 512 for the argument and 0.5235 radians

Comment: $512$ is the magnitude for $(4\sqrt3+4i)^3$; $\frac\pi 6 =0.5235...$ radians is the argument for $4\sqrt3+4i$